# How do I use ldapdelete to delete an improperly set up olc database?

Tags: ubuntu, ldap, openldap

I've been walking through [this tutorial](https://help.ubuntu.com/10.04/serverguide/C/openldap-server.html) and kept getting errors -- likely because I was typing it in manually -- so I retried, executing it after entering in

```
# Load dynamic backend modules
dn: cn=module,cn=config
objectClass: olcModuleList
cn: module
olcModulepath: /usr/lib/ldap
olcModuleload: back_hdb

# Database settings
dn: olcDatabase=hdb,cn=config
objectClass: olcDatabaseConfig
objectClass: olcHdbConfig
olcDatabase: {1}hdb
olcSuffix: dc=example,dc=local
olcDbDirectory: /var/lib/ldap
```

It worked, so I typed in the rest and re-executed:

```
sudo ldapadd -Y EXTERNAL -H ldapi:/// -f backend.example.com.ldif
```

and now it says

```
ldap_add: Other (e.g., implementation specific) error (80)
    additional info: <olcSuffix> namingContext "dc=home,dc=local" already served by a preceding hdb database
```

Which, as I would guess, means that it can't complete the ldapadd because one already exists under the same name.

I tried deleting it using ([from here](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/LDAP-HOWTO/utilities.html)):

```
sudo ldapdelete 'dc=example,dc=local'
```

and it's asking for a password, of which my password doesn't work and there was nothing set as the olcRootPW in the initial setup.

How do I use ldapdelete in this context so I can re-setup this database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wasn't able to figure out how to delete the database, but I had just started so I purged slapd and ldap-utils.

```
sudo apt-get purge slapd ldap-utils
```

and reinstalled.

Comment: Downvoted because although uninstalling and then reinstalling may work, it is rarely the correct answer. What Ignmar said below is much better advice.

Answer (score 7):

Generally the initial setup process for **cn=config** isn't very easy and there are plenty of ways to shoot yourself in the foot in the process. However, remember that **cn=config is** stored in LDIF format files in **slapd.d** (usually in `${prefix}/etc/openldap/`) and can be edited by hand (carefully and while slapd isn't running). So if you've locked yourself out (no RootDN/RootPW) or completely mangled your **cn=config** somehow, you can always fix it there.

A good way to get a basic config going is to actually do it in the old style **slapd.conf** fashion and then convert it to **slapd.d** (using `slaptest -f -F`) once the basic stuff (databases, modules and a RootDN/RootPW) is sorted.

Comment: Oh my God I have been avoiding a problem of duplicated `ppolicy` overlays for six months now and you have just ... wow ... thank you!!!

Comment: According to [this thread](https://www.openldap.org/lists/openldap-technical/201307/msg00219.html) `cn=config` simply does not support deletions until slapd 2.5